# Can't convert object of type ArrayList to my model

Tags: java, listview, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

While trying to carry out the implementation of a simple chat application using firebase, i am encountering this error logged below.
One thing i noticed is, the previous messages will load but an instance of me trying to swipe to the last messages, then the application crashes while giving out the log below.
I will sincerely appreciate an assistance to helping to understand the cause of this.
Thanks

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object
>   of type java.util.ArrayList to type chat.ChatMessage
>                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseListAdapter.java:120)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.getItem(FirebaseListAdapter.java:109)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.getView(FirebaseListAdapter.java:137)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2485)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1945)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:710)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:674)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5534)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:5030)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
>                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
>                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:571)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5682)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:963)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)

This is the ChatMessage model i am using

```
public class ChatMessage {

    private String messageText;
    private String messageUser;
    private long messageTime;

    public ChatMessage(String messageText, String messageUser) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
        this.messageUser = messageUser;
        messageTime = new Date().getTime();
    }

    public ChatMessage(){

    }

    public String getMessageText() {
        return messageText;
    }

    public void setMessageText(String messageText) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
    }

    public String getMessageUser() {
        return messageUser;
    }

    public void setMessageUser(String messageUser) {
        this.messageUser = messageUser;
    }

    public long getMessageTime() {
        return messageTime;
    }

    public void setMessageTime(long messageTime) {
        this.messageTime = messageTime;
    }
}
```

My displayChat message is

```
private void displayChatMessages() throws DatabaseException {
        ListView listOfMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);
try{
        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,
                R.layout.message_activity, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
                // Get references to the views of message.xml
                TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                TextView messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

                // Set their text
                messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
                messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
                messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                        model.getMessageTime()));
            }
        };

        listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    }catch (DatabaseException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

Comment: i followed the tutorial on this [git](https://github.com/tutsplus/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase)

Comment: you are retrieving a list of elements and want to convert it to on object, you need to declare an `ArrayList<MessageChat>` and set it the returned data

Comment: thanks so much for your time...I will so much appreciate how i am going to go about its implementation please.

Comment: you need to share some of your code so we can help you more

Comment: the code i am using is same as the one [here](https://github.com/tutsplus/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase) thanks once again